# Closed Graph Theorem and Spaces Of Continuous Functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a (Tychonoff) topological space. Consider $C\left(X\right)$ being a topological vector space of all continuous scalar-valued functions with the compact-open topology.

Assume that $Y$ is a barreled space and $T$ is a linear map from $Y$ into $C\left(X\right)$ having a closed graph.

Could you please advice me the conditions on $X$, which would allow to apply the Closed Graph Theorem?

Clearly the assumption that $C\left(X\right)$ is an F-space (which is equivalent for $X$ to be hemicompact and compactly generated) is sufficient, but these two conditions are too restrictive.

For instance, it would be wonderful, if the second assumption alone was enough.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried bourbaki?

Comment: This should be a comment but I don't have enough brownie points. Firstly, I don't understand the downvote(s)---seems an interesting and highly non-trivial question to me. I would suggest the monograph "Topics in locally convex spaces" by Valdivia which has several delicate versions of the closed graph theorems in chapter 4 but this would then leave you with the task of pinpointing topological properties of $X$ which dualise to the corresponding ones for the lcs $C(X)$.Other sources for less standard CGT's are the classical text of Gottfried Köthe and the works of Pták and de Wilde.

Comment: In fact my question is exactly about "pinpointing topological properties of X which dualise 
to the corresponding ones for the lcs $C\left(X\right)$. For example in Kelly-Namioka, they give few sufficient conditions for Closed Graph Theorem to hold, including hypercompleteness and full completeness, but I have no idea which properties of $X$ are needed for this.

Comment: There are Springer Lecture Notes of Jean Schmets about locally convex properties of $C(X)$ (SLN 519, *Espaces de fonctions continue*, 1976).

Comment: Once again, this is a comment not an answer but the system doesn't let me even comment on my own comments. Want to repeat the fact that I am completely gobsmacked by the fact that a question of this subtlety not only received downvotes but there were even attempts to close it (notabene by someone whose field of expertise is group theory).

Comment: I second @blackburne's comment(s)

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth: thank you for the reference. Unfortunately I don't know French (it is written in French, right?), but it seems that in the book the author ascertains which properties of $X$ correspond to barreledness-like properties of $C\left(X\right)$, which is not exactly the same as completeness properties, which stand behind the Closed Graph Theorems. The same properties are considered in the sequel, by the way, which is written in English.